# TS ES6 - Building Library - Export Issues

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have built a server library package that I am want to use for all my programs by importing as the "Base/Core" server program.  To use it as an API, I am doing this in the `index.ts`.

```
import { MainServer } from './server-app'; //Want for Type

export class Server {
    private static _serverConfig = null;
    private static _mainDB = null;
    private static _supportDB = null;
    private static _mainServer: MainServer = null;  //Heres type
    private static _client = '';

    constructor(serverConfig, client: string) {
        Server._serverConfig = serverConfig;
        Server._client = client;
    }

    public static async connectAndRun() {
        //Connect then Server._mainDB = db;
        ....
    }

    public static getClientName() {
        return this._client;
    }

    public static getMainServer() {
        return Server._mainServer;
    }

    public static getMainDB() {
        return Server._mainDB;
    }

    public static getSupportDB() {
        return Server._supportDB;
    }
}

export * from './server-app'; //Need for the API to have access to all variables needed
```

I am getting errors when `import { MainServer } from './server-app';` as well as `export * from './server-app';` because inside `server-app.ts`, I am doing more exports such as this:

`export * from './collections/app-version.collection';`

Inside that file, I have such:

```
import { Server } from '../index';
import { AppVersionModel } from '../models/app-version.model';

let schema: any = {
    _id: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    ...
};

export const AppVersions: Model<ServerModel> = Server.getMainDB().model('app-versions', Schema);
```

So its trying to use `Server.getMainDB()` which the server is undefined because it's importing in index.ts before my Server is finished it's construction as well as before my DB is connected and defined.

I understand why index.ts needs all the exports, but I do not understand how to export everything without having dependency/import/export issues.

Comment: (Not related to your circular dependency problem, but) You should either drop `static` from all the method and properties, or not use `class` syntax

Comment: Can you post code related to MainServer as well. Basically you need to get rid of circular dependencies by either using type or interface declarations and importing them into Server and MainServer code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by generating a index.d.ts typings file with all the export declare functions/constants needed.